# Manual entry for history missing... `man history`

Tags: bash, command-history, man, shell-builtin

I'm trying to figure out what's going on with my history... but I can't find the manual

`history -h` returns nothing `man history` returns a level 8 history manual, not the bash one we all use.

Answer (score 1):

`history` is one of many `bash` built-ins, so many they felt listing it out in their man page would bring more harm than good. That said, `bash` does have its own manual system for built-ins such as `fc` and `test`. To access the manual for `history`, use

```
help history
```

in a `bash` session.

Or get a summary of the command in the ~6000 line `bash` manual

```
# Jump to the entry in Ubuntu/Fedora/MacOS
man -P 'less -p "  history \["' bash
```

Sources:
https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/history.def
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html